# Which is the referent of "its" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, reference, it-its-itself

This is the sentence:

> The auto-negotiating device will link at the speed of the non-negotiating device, and set **its** port to half-duplex mode.

Can someone explain on what is being referred here when "its" is mentioned?

Its = Auto-negotiating device?
Its = Non-negotiating device?

Which does it indicate and why?

Comment: It's ambiguous.

Comment: @fev, thank you for your comment. Usually, when such a sentence formation occurs, what does the "its" point to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Antecedent Precedence? (antededent of 'it')](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127875/antecedent-precedence-antededent-of-it)

Comment: This is a particular context, and the OP does not ask for a general rule, but how the rule applies to this particular context. I wouldn't close it as a dupe, dear folks. And I wouldn't DV both the question and the answer for this reason.

Comment: The sentence is straightforwardly ambiguous. _Its port_ may refer to either device's port. That makes it a bad choice. Why not mention the device instead of passing along the job of guessing to the reader? It's grammatical, all right, but it's pretty useless.

Comment: Logically, it seems pretty unlikely that a "non-negotiating device" would allow some *external* device to reconfigure its (the non-negotiating device's) ports. Software firewalls wouldn't be much good if that was standard practice. But that's real-world logic and reasoning - nothing to do with the fact that *syntactically* the cited text is ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

It can be ambiguous, but from the structure of the sentence I would say it refers to the subject of the first main clause. Consider:

> The auto-negotiating device will link at the speed of the non-negotiating device, and [***the auto-negotiating device will***] set its port to half-duplex mode.

If you write the second clause on its own it would be:

> The auto-negotiating device will set its port to half-duplex mode.

I doubt ***its*** refers to a different device. It may be helpful to add ***own*** (*its own port*), to get rid of any ambiguity.

Comment: — I agree. An auto-negotiating device chooses its settings (its own settings; not those of other devices) to connect optimally to the network.

Comment: @Segorian While you were writing your comment I was adding my suggestion to use "own" in order to make it unambiguous.

Comment: +1. This was my reasoning as well.

Comment: As @FumbleFingers, and setting itself to half-duplex mode also suggests creating a basic connection with the non-negotiating device.